# Como sacar la id de un grupo en telegram

Tags: api

Hola quiero sacar el id de un grupo en telegram para poder usar una pequeña aplicacion en telegram que he hecho pero de momento no se como. 
Por ejemplo este grupo:

```
https://telegram.me/joinchat/Ag2Zdj2NIFy3WPs0QP9Fjg
```

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicacion para telegram usando la google api para traducir texto de cualquier mensaje a un idioma que el usuario elija. Pero no se como puedo obtener el id del grupo.
Intente seguir los pasos de [uno de los post de stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423837/telegram-bot-how-to-get-a-group-chat-id-ruby-gem-telegram-bot)

Pero cuando hago lo que se detalla alli que es lo siguiente con el grupo:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botAg2Zdj2NIFy3WPs0QP9Fjg/getUpdates
```

Me devuelve:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}
```

**Como podría solucionarlo para poder obtener el id del grupo?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tu error está en el Token que colocas.**
Le falta una parte.

La URL debe ser del formato:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot@@@@@@@@@:########################/getUpdates
```

Donde hay 9 arrobas (@) y 35 numerales (#).

El Token que tu colocaste no posee esa cantidad de caracteres.

Recuerda que el Token de tu Bot debes pedirselo al @BotFather, el Robot de Telegram que te permite crear otros Bots.

*Si te fijas bien tu compartiste (en parte) el Token de tu BOT, recuerda que eso puede ser perjudicial para ti, editalo.*

La respuesta de la API debe ser algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde te devolverá el ID de Grupo que necesitas.

Comment: hola tengo una duda y te la pregunto aqui porque esta relacionado con el tema yo no puedo saber el token bot de otro grupo?

Comment: Hola Jeronimo. Si mi respuesta ha sido la acertada y has logrado lograr tu cometido deberías votarlo como la correcta. Con respecto a tu pregunta en el comentario me temo que el único que puede ver el Token de un Bot es el usuario que lo creo, que en este caso si no eres tu no lo podrás ver. Ya que el token es la llave por la cual solo el dueño puede hacer uso de el mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma sencilla de sacar el id de los chat de Telegram es ingresando vía web a la aplicación ([Telegram Web](https://web.telegram.org/#/im)), buscamos el grupo que queremos saber su id y vamos a buscar en la URL de la página, el siguiente parámetro enviado por GET

```
"...p=sXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..."

(Donde X son números)
```

Tomamos los primeros 10 números en la cadena antes del guión bajo, después de la "s" y solo le agregamos antes un "-100" y ya ese es el id del grupo.

**Ejemplo:**

```
Para ...p=s1234567890_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX... <br>
idChat= -1001234567890
```

Yo ocupo bots para enviar mensajes a mis grupos de telegram vía NodeJS.